# добавление элемента в SimpleListProperty

Tags: java, javafx

у меня есть такая строка

```
    private ListProperty<String> nameLink = new SimpleListProperty<>();
```

Я хочу в конструкторе добавить пару элементов для проверки работоспособности программы, но с этим возникли проблемы, как я понимаю `= new SimpleListProperty<>()` создает мне объект типа именно `SimpleListProperty<>`, но в нем методов добавления элементов нет, так же я могу воспользоваться методами `ListProperty<>`, и там я нашел

```
public void setValue(ObservableList<E> v) {
    set(v);
}
```

Как я понимаю, используя этот метод, я должен использовать коллекцию типа `ObservableList`, но я по факту хочу просто добавить элемент типа `String`. Так же среда мне подсказывает метод - `add();` я передаю туда к примеру `"qwe"`, на что мне выдает огромное исключение, так вот, как в мою коллекцию передавать обычную строку?

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15457814/9719337) А вообще, вы создаете `ListProperty` что является списком. Вы же в обычный список не передаете просто строку, вы эту самую строку добавляете. В данном случае, вам нужно обернуть строку в `ObservableList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно инициализировать каким-либо списком в конструкторе `new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());`

`SimpleListProperty` - это НЕ совсем список, а обертка над ObservableList, но при этом реализующая его интерфейс.

`nameLink.get()` - вернет список, в который можно добавлять элементы (переданный в конструкторе).
`nameLink.set(...)` - заменит список внутри свойства `nameLink`, но обычно это не то что нужно.

Также доступны обычные методы add, remove и т.д., на реализацию можно посмотреть в классе `javafx.beans.binding.ListExpression`, но если в `SimpleListProperty` не передать свой список, то будет использоваться значение по-умолчанию - `FXCollections.emptyObservableList()` - которое не допускает изменений (будут бросаться исключения)